# How do I make an incoming negative signal a positive one?

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

I am looking for a way to make a negative signal to a positive one. A positive signal has to stay positive. Does someone know how it can be done?

Comment: Can be done with an opamp and a diode. See my question here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/372779/unsigned-op-amp-output

Comment: Use an op-amp inverting amplifier...

Comment: [Precision Rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier)

Comment: Or add a suitable DC offset. Question is too unclear to answer, more context required.

Comment: Swap the input wires? Need details on the nature of this 'negative' signal. Why does it need to 'stay positive'?

Comment: @BruceAbbott lol, that occurred to me first too:)